# Using OpenXML read the existing file and append some rows with data, then return it as bytes so as to download the form

Tags: c#, download, openxml

```
public static byte[] AddDataToPredifinedFormat(string path, string sheetName = "")
{
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    var employee = new List<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee{Name = "XYZ", Number = "12345"},
                    new Employee{Name = "ABC", Number = "12345"}
                };
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = wbPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
                string sheetId = sheetName != "" ? sheets.Where(q => q.Name == sheetName).First().Id.Value : sheets.First().Id.Value;
                WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)wbPart.GetPartById(sheetId);
                SheetData sheetData = wsPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                foreach (var x in employee)
                {
                    Row newRow = new Row();
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(x.Name.ToString());
                    cell.StyleIndex = 0;
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }
                wbPart.Workbook.Save(ms);
                fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return fileBytes;
}
```

Reading the existing file and appending rows but on downloading the file, Excel app shows it's corrupted.
Using OpenXML read the existing file and append some rows with data, then return it as bytes so as to download the form

Comment: There isn't any question here! please review it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in order to return the sheet you need to need to refactor code a little. Instead of expecting the memory stream to write directly to array and download file wont help,
What i did is in my code:

- Write data to stream and read that back. So you need to return the updated stream
- Write the stream data to ExcelPackage

Something like this

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(<process and return your steam>);
  using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                //write any more extra data to sheet
                return package.GetAsByteArray();
            }
```

Important bit to notice is : **package.GetAsByteArray();**

Comment: Thanks.. Ur's solutions helped me but in that as we are returning the package in the form of byte[] there is no need of using stream.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving `fileBytes = ms.ToArray();` to outside of the inner `using` block?

I have very similar code to this for modifying WordprocessingDocuments with OpenXML but I don't use MemoryStream.  I `File.Copy` the original to a temporary file, modify, save and then load the `byte[]` from the temporary file for streaming.

Comment: Can u provide the code what you are having ..  So that will be helpful... moving fileBytes outside of using didn't solved the problem

Comment: For debugging this, it might be helpful to take both your original .xlsx and your modified .xlsx, change the extensions to .zip, unzip and then compare the contents of worksheets\sheetname.xml to see how your code is changing the XML.